# How to wrap around a figure in a theorem-like environment?

Tags: floats, theorems, wrapfigure

I want to illustrate my examples, which are set in a theorem-like environment. Is it possible to wrap the text and equations around the figures? I have read about several packages but I can't get them to work in a theorem. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the `cutwin` package but it's possible to use it  with the `picins`. This package is not actually in TeXLive (we can find it now [here](http://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/picins/)).

I use `windowpagestuff` from the `cutwin` package to stock the picture with the caption, then I get the width of the picture. It's not sure that all of this stuff is robust but it's interesting to try ...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{picins}   
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\newtheorem{exam}{Example}
\newbox\mybox 
\newdimen\myboxwidth    

\newcommand\addpicture[3]{% 
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=#3]{#2}}
\myboxwidth\wd\mybox    
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{% 
\includegraphics[scale=#3]{#2}
\captionof{figure}{A test figure.}}
\parpic[#1]{% 
\begin{minipage}{\myboxwidth}
 \windowpagestuff 
\end{minipage} 
} }
\begin{document}

\begin{exam}
\lipsum[1]
\addpicture{s}{tiger.pdf}{0.2}
\lipsum[1]    
\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And with this approach you can use displayed math environments (`equation`, `align`, etc.); at least that's why my tests suggest.

Answer (score 7):

The `wrapfig` package won't behave well with theorem-like structures created with `amsthm` or `ntheorem`. The [cutwin](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cutwin) package can be used with those theorem-like structures (see my example below) as long as only text is involved. However, none of those packages interacts well with displayed math.

A little example of the text of a theorem-like structure wrapped around a figure with caption, using the `cutwin` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=no}
\newtheorem{exam}{Example}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%
  \includegraphics[height=4cm, width=5cm]{figure}
  \captionof{figure}{A test figure.}
}
\opencutleft
\begin{exam}
  \begin{cutout}{2}{0pt}{0.5\linewidth}{13}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{cutout}
\end{exam}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work at all in many environments that I use.  For example in the springer lncs example environment this glitches and overwrites paragraphs on top of others.

Comment: @ArlenCox well, and what did you expect? Classes which are not the standard ones redefine a lot of things. Feel free to open a new question with that class or contact the author/maintainer of the class and ask for a solution there.

Comment: Worked for me, is there a way to have different pictures for different examples?

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked @Altermundus' solution, which does indeed work inside theorems with maths:

```
\RequirePackage{xparse, graphicx, caption, picins}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \addpic{O{0.4\textwidth} m g}{\parpic[r]{%
\begin{minipage}{#1}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#2}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{\captionof{figure}{\footnotesize #3}}
\end{minipage}
}}
```

Now I can call `addpic` using `addpic{filename}`, `addpic[width]{filename}`, `addpic{filename}{caption}`, or `addpic[width]{filename}{caption}`.