# Problem with parpic and compactenum

Tags: graphics, positioning, picins

I want to place a graphics to the right in a theorem environment containing a `compactenum` list. I tried to use `parpic` like this, but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}%
\newtheorem{test}{test}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
   \parpic[r]{\includegraphics[draft,width=6cm]{test.jpg}}
   Text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text,
   text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,
   \begin{compactenum}[a)]
      \item  text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text
      \item  text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text
   \end{compactenum}
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

Any idea how to fix this?

*Edit:*

I tried also Nicolás's solution below, however the image is not aligned at the top, this becomes clear if I add more text like this:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newtheorem{test}{test}
\begin{document}

 \noindent\parbox[b][][s]{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm-5mm}{%
    \begin{test}
       Text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text,
       text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,
          \begin{itemize}
             \item  text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text
             \item  \blindtext

          \end{itemize}
    \end{test}
    } \hfill
    \includegraphics[draft,height=4cm, width=5cm]{imageName}

\end{document}
```

[image: parbox]

Comment: This answer may be useful for you (credits to @GonzaloMedina): http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14826/5185

Comment: @Nicolás Could you give some more details how to adapt this to my example?

Comment: That approach didn't work, so I tried another one that I'm going to write as an answer right now.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is not as clean as I would have wanted, but it works anyway.

What you should do is:

1. Enclose your `theorem` environment inside a `parbox`.
2. Right after it you write:

   - `hfill`
   - Include the image with `includegraphics`:

So, the code you get is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{test}{Test theorem}

\begin{document}

    \noindent\parbox[b][][s]{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm-5mm}{%
    \begin{test}
       Text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text,
       text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,
          \begin{itemize}
             \item  text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text
             \item  text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text
          \end{itemize}
    \end{test}
    } \hfill
    \includegraphics[height=4cm, width=5cm]{imageName}

\end{document}
```

I hope that it helps.

Comment: I guess it might be better to use a more image-oriented width for you `\parbox`. For example, `\noindent\parbox[b][][s]{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}` rather than `\parbox[b][][s]{0.5\textwidth}`, since the latter has no reference to the image width of `5cm`.

Comment: @Werner: very good suggestion. I've just edited my answer to incorporate what you said, but I made the parbox `5mm` narrower so that there is a small space between the text and the image.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two `minipage`s with top alignment and `\raisebox` to place the image:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newtheorem{test}{test}

\begin{document}

 \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm-5mm}
\begin{test}
Text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text,
text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,
  \begin{itemize}
    \item  text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text,  text, text
    \item  \blindtext
  \end{itemize}
\end{test}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[draft,height=4cm, width=5cm]{imageName}}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]