# What's the correct way to place theorems and pictures side by side?

Tags: tables, theorems, wrapfigure

Okay so I have a definition using the `amsthm` `theorem` environments, and a `tikzpicture` which I want to see side by side. The material inside the definition is not too big, so I expect the final height of the two to be about the same. `wrapfig` does not work inside the `definition` environment because it's a list. I could not get `cutwin` to work, it puts the picture right after "Definition." and the text below.

Then I tried `tabularx` (`tabular` gives me some `missing \item` error) which seems to approximate what I want the best, but somehow places the two on different rows, even though the code is like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,amsthm,tikz}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X r}
\begin{definition}
Blah blah blah 
\end{definition} & \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Is there a good way of doing this?

(P.S. I'm not sure what tags are appropriate for this.)

Comment: Are yuu sure this is a good idea from a reader stand point?

Comment: @daleif Well, the picture is supposed to be a diagram of what I'm defining. Is this considered bad practice for some reason? I myself find this useful as a reader.

Comment: Trying to wrap a definition around an image, does not look well in my opinion. Do it as a normal figure instead.

Comment: @daleif I have encountered this occasionally in certain geometry/topology related texts, see for example page 43 in http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf, although with an "Example" instead of "Definition". Or even page 17 in the same file, where I believe he uses his own styled definition environment. So to convince me away, you'll need something better than "does not look well in my opinion". Even if I decide not to do this, I would still like to know a way of solving this problem. (Btw, my page numbers are wrt the pdf, not the book's page numbers)

Comment: Hatchers book is also the only example I can think of. Personally I find it anoying to read. I don't remember how he actually did that, but it might be a lot of paragraph shapes. I don't remember if it is written in LaTeX or plain TeX.

Comment: Have you checked out the answers to this question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14825/how-to-wrap-around-a-figure-in-a-theorem-like-environment

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. The answers papabravo's linked question are probably solutions, but without feedback from the OP, it's impossible to say.

Comment: I think it's fine to close this as duplicate of the question linked by papabravo.