# How to wrap figures in theorems with formulas?

Tags: graphics, wrap

I am writing my first book. I need to wrap figures. I want text to flow it. I am searching in the internet the best way to do it. I need it in theorems with formulas. And way from the topic below is the best, but here is problem. It doesn't work with formulas properly! Look at the screenhot. Awful! I can't correct it manually.

PS. I do not need exactly this way of adding pictures. If you know correct way which works with theorems, formulas, tell me please.

[How to wrap around a figure in a theorem-like environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14825/how-to-wrap-around-a-figure-in-a-theorem-like-environment)

this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

this is normal, but without formulas:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[russian]{babel}


\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amscd}   
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{picins}   
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{cutwin}


\newbox\mybox 
\newdimen\myboxwidth    

\newcommand\addpicture[3]{% 
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=#3]{#2}}
\myboxwidth\wd\mybox    
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{% 
\includegraphics[scale=#3]{#2}
\captionof{figure}{}}
\parpic[#1]{% 
\begin{minipage}{\myboxwidth}
 \windowpagestuff 
\end{minipage} 
} }

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Теорема}
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[о существовании и единственности неявной функции, заданной одним уравнением]\label{yaa14th1}
Пусть функция $F(x,y)$ определена и непрерывна в некоторой $\delta$-окрестности точки $(x_0,y_0)$, и пусть $F(x_0,y_0)=0$. Тогда, если $F(x,y)$ при каждом фиксированном $x$ строго монотонна по $y$, то у точек $x_0$ и $y_0$ существуют окрестности $\Delta$ и $(a;b)$ такие, что на множестве $\Delta\times(a;b)$ уравнение $F(x,y)=0$ определяет единственную неявную функцию $y=f(x),\; x\in\Delta$, и эта функция  $f$ непрерывна на $\Delta$. 
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}

По условию функция $F(x_0,y)$ строго монотонна и равна нулю при  $y_0$.\addpicture{r}{ch9pict1.png}{0.47} Пусть для определенности, она строго возрастает. Тогда $F(x_0,y)>0$ для всех допустимых $y>0$ и $F(x_0,y)<0$ для всех допустимых $y<y_0$.
Выберем некоторые $a$ и $b$ такие, что $a<y_0<b$ и точки $(x_0,a)$, $(x_0,b)$ лежать в $\delta$-окрестности точки $(x_0,y_0)$. Тогда
$$
F(x_0,a)<0<F(x_0,b).
$$



Функции $F(x,a)$ и $F(x,b)$ непрерывны в точке $x_0$, поэтому существуют окрестности $\Delta'$ и $\Delta''$ точки $x_0$ такие, что (рис.)
$$
F(x,a)<0 \quad \forall x\in \Delta', \qquad F(x,b)>0\quad \forall x\in \Delta''.
$$



Отсюда следует, что $F(x,a)<0<F(x,b)$ для любого $x$ из интервала $\Delta = \Delta'\cap\Delta''$. А так как функция $F(x,y)$ при каждом фиксированном $x\in\Delta$ по $y$ непрерывна и строго монотонна, то для каждого $x\in \Delta$ существует единственное $y$, которое обозначим $f(x)$, такое что $f(x)\in(a;b)$ и $F(x,f(x))=0$. Следовательно, на прямоугольнике $\Delta\times(a;b)$ уравнение $F(x,y)=0$ определяет единственную неявную функцию $y=f(x)$. Докажем, что она непрерывна в точке $x_0$

Выберем некоторую окрестность $(\alpha;\beta)$ точки $y_0$. Не ограничивая общности, будем считать, что $(\alpha;\beta)\subset (a;b)$. Тогда точно также, как и для интервала $(a,b)$, строится окрестность $\Delta=\Delta(\alpha;\beta)$ точки $x_0$ такая, что $\forall x\in\Delta \quad f(x)\in(\alpha;\beta)$. А это и означает, что функция $f$ непрерывна в точке $x_0$.

Непрерывность функции $y=f(x)$ в любой точке $x_1\in\Delta$ следует из того, что в точке с координатами $x_1$ и $y_1=f(x_1)$ выполнены все условия теоремы, поэтому, согласно доказанному, у точки $(x_1,y_1)$ существует прямоугольная окрестность, в которой уравнение $F(x,y)=0$ определяет единственную функцию $y=f(x_1),\;x\in\Delta_1$, которая непрерывна в точке $x_1$. Очевидно, что $f_1(x)=f(x)\quad \forall x\in\Delta\cap\Delta_1$, и поэтому функция $f(x)$ непрерывна в точке $x_1\in\Delta$.

Теорема доказана.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note: you ought to find out a way to include example pictures everyone has. There should be some way to include pictures that come with a package or the likes.

Comment: Also, [see this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: For code readability, I would suggest putting the `\addpicture`s on a line by themselves instead of in the middle of the text.

Comment: And I will get the second printscreen with your suggestion. It is worse...

Comment: Hm, doesn't change anything on my computer…

Comment: Unfortunately, `picins` is not well-documented, and I have no idea what the other parameters to `\parpic` are for. `\parpic(<dimen>,<dimen>)(<dimen>,<dimen>)[…][……]{………}` is the full syntax. It appears the third `dimen` moves the picture sideways and the fourth one moves it vertically, but the first two I have no idea what they are for, and the `……` is a mystery.

Comment: You'll have to wait for someone else to see this, I can't answer…

Comment: oh, I do not need exactly this way of adding pictures. If you know correct way which works with theorems, formulas, tell me please.

Comment: \parpic(width,height)(x-offset,y-offset)[Options][Position]{Picture}

Comment: Actually, I don't know. I usually just wrap them in a `center`, never mixed them with text. But you can try using `wrapfig` or `atbegshi` (just naming packages I have seen named in wrapping picture questions).

Comment: `(width,height)` of what?

Comment: <<If the width and height are not given [in which case also no offsets
can be given] or if they are given as 0pt, the actual size of the
Picture is used.>>

I guess, of area for picture...

Comment: OK. `atbegshi` is a wrong memory I had. Nothing to do with pictures :).

Comment: and `wrapfig` does not work in theorems...

Comment: Seems it works in no environment at all…

Comment: Tried `floatflt` but the result was [even stranger](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DtTB9.png).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which relies on the `threeparttable` package and the `insbox` set of macros. I define a `\myaddpicture` command, which uses an optional argument and two mandatory arguments (the graphic file and its scaling). The optional argument is a correction for the number of shorter lines (5 by default, in order to place the caption).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Теорема}
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}

\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newcommand\myaddpicture[3][6]{%
\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{threeparttable}\begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[scale=#3]{#2}\end{tabular}\captionof{figure}{}\end{threeparttable}}[#1]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[о существовании и единственности неявной функции, заданной одним уравнением]\label{yaa14th1}
  Пусть функция $F(x,y)$ определена и непрерывна в некоторой $\delta$-окрестности точки $(x_0,y_0)$, и пусть $F(x_0,y_0)=0$. Тогда, если $F(x,y)$ при каждом фиксированном $x$ строго монотонна по $y$, то у точек $x_0$ и $y_0$ существуют окрестности $\Delta$ и $(a;b)$ такие, что на множестве $\Delta\times(a;b)$ уравнение $F(x,y)=0$ определяет единственную неявную функцию $y=f(x),\; x\in\Delta$, и эта функция $f$ непрерывна на $\Delta$.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}

  По условию функция $F(x_0,y)$ строго монотонна и равна нулю при $y_0$.%\addpicture{r}{ch9pict1.png}{0.47}
  \myaddpicture{ch9pict1.png}{0.47}
  Пусть для определенности, она строго возрастает. Тогда $F(x_0,y)>0$ для всех допустимых $y>0$ и $F(x_0,y)<0$ для всех допустимых $y<y_0$.
  Выберем некоторые $a$ и $b$ такие, что $a<y_0<b$ и точки $(x_0,a)$, $(x_0,b)$ лежать в $\delta$-окрестности точки $(x_0,y_0)$. Тогда
  $$
  F(x_0,a)<0<F(x_0,b).
  $$



  Функции $F(x,a)$ и $F(x,b)$ непрерывны в точке $x_0$, поэтому существуют окрестности $\Delta'$ и $\Delta''$ точки $x_0$ такие, что (рис.)
  \[
  F(x,a)<0 \quad \forall x\in \Delta', \qquad F(x,b)>0\quad \forall x\in \Delta''.
   \]

  Отсюда следует, что $F(x,a)<0<F(x,b)$ для любого $x$ из интервала $\Delta = \Delta'\cap\Delta''$. А так как функция $F(x,y)$ при каждом фиксированном $x\in\Delta$ по $y$ непрерывна и строго монотонна, то для каждого $x\in \Delta$ существует единственное $y$, которое обозначим $f(x)$, такое что $f(x)\in(a;b)$ и $F(x,f(x))=0$. Следовательно, на прямоугольнике $\Delta\times(a;b)$ уравнение $F(x,y)=0$ определяет единственную неявную функцию $y=f(x)$. Докажем, что она непрерывна в точке $x_0$
  \myaddpicture{ch9pict1.png}{0.47}

  Выберем некоторую окрестность $(\alpha;\beta)$ точки $y_0$. Не ограничивая общности, будем считать, что $(\alpha;\beta)\subset (a;b)$. Тогда точно также, как и для интервала $(a,b)$, строится окрестность $\Delta=\Delta(\alpha;\beta)$ точки $x_0$ такая, что $\forall x\in\Delta \quad f(x)\in(\alpha;\beta)$. А это и означает, что функция $f$ непрерывна в точке $x_0$.

  Непрерывность функции $y=f(x)$ в любой точке $x_1\in\Delta$ следует из того, что в точке с координатами $x_1$ и $y_1=f(x_1)$ выполнены все условия теоремы, поэтому, согласно доказанному, у точки $(x_1,y_1)$ существует прямоугольная окрестность, в которой уравнение $F(x,y)=0$ определяет единственную функцию $y=f(x_1),\;x\in\Delta_1$, которая непрерывна в точке $x_1$. Очевидно, что $f_1(x)=f(x)\quad \forall x\in\Delta\cap\Delta_1$, и поэтому функция $f(x)$ непрерывна в точке $x_1\in\Delta$.

  Теорема доказана.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but I get only black squares. How can I get pictures :(

Comment: This comes from the `demo` option for `graphics`, as I don't have your pictures. Remove the option.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. And it works! Thanks, man.
And If I put `\myaddpicture` exactly after `\begin{proof}` I will get awful effect. But It is not a big deal.

Comment: Add `\leavevmode` before `\myaddpicture`. Naturally, you can have pictures on the left with the `\InsertBoxL` command instead of `InsertBoxR` (but you'll have some problems at the beginning of the proof environment).

Comment: And last question. How can I refer this picture? Usual way \label \ref do not work properly

Comment: I don't see at the moment how to add labels to the macro. I don't really have time at the moment, and will give a try tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, it will be great. And there is another question. See your screenshot. Words "Пусть для определенности" are on another line, another paragraph. But I do not want to break paragragh, because it is not a new paragraph . And I do not want to see the word "Доказательство" alone on a line by itself. Heh, may be it is too much. but if it is possible...

Comment: And I hope, last. I want to do `InsertBoxR` on odd pages. and `InsertBoxL` on the even pages. How can I differ this (except manually)?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297627/how-to-wrap-pictures-in-lists-in-theorems-with-formulas @Bernard see it please