# How do I wrap a picture when it is right after environment \begin?

Tags: graphics, insbox

I am trying to wrap pictures in environments. I've seen people there recommend using `insbox.tex` in different answers. Everything is fine with my code below. However, when picture is introduced right after `\begin{group}` it simply doesn't work.

[image]

Edit: I don't to `\leavevmode` that.

Look at my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommand\insertpictureR[3][5]{
\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{threeparttable}\begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}\captionof{figure}{}\end{threeparttable}}[#1]%
}
\newcommand\insertpictureL[3][5]{
\InsertBoxL{0}{\begin{threeparttable}\begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}\captionof{figure}{}\end{threeparttable}}[#1]%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\insertpictureR{example-image-a}{0.2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
\insertpictureL{example-image-a}{0.2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need a threeparttable environment?

Comment: @Bernard `wrapfig` package in this case solve the problem? My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I doubt that, because theorem-like structures are lists, as a last resort. That's why `insbox` often works better, because it's based on plain TeX.

Comment: @Bernard to be honest, it is just a function from your answer long ago. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297595/98432

I still use it :) But today I've got this problem. Well, probably I need to try another approach at all... like dividing it into 2 minipages, but that seems to be so unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a `\leavevmode` and some other goodies.  Note your macro seems to systematically require using the optional argument (maybe the caption height is not taken into account correctly?).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommand\insertpictureR[3][5]{
\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{threeparttable}\begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}\captionof{figure}{}\end{threeparttable}}[#1]%
}
\newcommand\insertpictureL[3][5]{
\InsertBoxL{0}{\begin{threeparttable}\begin{tabular}{c@{}}\includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}\captionof{figure}{}\end{threeparttable}}[#1]%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm} \leavevmode
\insertpictureR[3]{example-image-a}{0.2}\noindent
\lipsum[1]
\end{thm}%



\begin{proof}
\leavevmode\insertpictureL[3]{example-image-a}{0.2}\noindent
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh no, I don't want to leavemode that... should have said that. I don't like leaving an almost empty line.

Comment: and yes, threeparttable makes counting lines wrong

Comment: I understand, but the only case I know how to deal with are standard lists, because we can easily play with right margins thanks to `enumitem`.

Comment: Note the image can start at the label line if you recode your command as `\InsertBoxR{-1}{...}`. So the label will feel less lonely…

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Does this way eliminate the problem due to a list environment?

Comment: After more experiments, no.  You could use \nopar and minipages (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157110/wrapping-image-with-multiple-theorem-like-environments-and-displayed-math/157370?r=SearchResults&s=8|8.1246#157370 for example).